# How to change multiple sheets specific column into 6 decimal using python(openpyxl)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, openpyxl

```
import os
import openpyxl

path = os.getcwd()
ipath = os.path.join(path,"Input")
files = os.listdir(ipath)
opath = os.path.join(path,"Output")
filepath1 = r"C:\Users\bubai\Desktop\Python_Try_projrct\off\Input\ds3.xlsx"
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath1)
#All sheet name
sheets = wb1.sheetnames
print(sheets)

ws = wb1["Sheet1"]
#x = ("E","G","H")
for cell in ws['E']:
    ws[cell.coordinate].number_format = '0.0000000'
    print(cell.value)
wb1.save(filepath1)
```

This Excel file contains multiple sheets, and I want to modify a particular column on each sheet to 6 decimal places.
[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet2]
1-suppose in sheet1 I want to change columns E, F, and G into 6 decimal

2-In Sheet2 I want to change the columns F,G, H, I.

Comment: What do you mean by "6 decimals". How do you want 5615.69 to be shown

Comment: means value is in 2 decimal like 5615.69 but I want it in 5615.690000